# Javascript toString() method on timezone gives different results since I used node 10 on Mac Terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

I am using iTerm (I got the same issue with Mac Terminal) for running Jest snapshot tests, where dates are stringified with their timezone. But since I have updated into a node 10.14.1 (npm 6.4.1), I got this difference:

`date="Mon Jan 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"`

`date="Mon Jan 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)"`

This difference doesn't come when I am running my test on other terminal (IntelliJ Terminal or on my docker environment)

I am using last version of Jest.

iTerm2 version: build 3.26
OS version: MacOS Mojave 10.14.2

Answer (score 0):

According to [`Date.toString()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) (note bold fragment):

> Optionally, a timezone name consisting of:
>
> - space
> - Left bracket, i.e. "("
> - An **implementation dependent string representation of the timezone**, which might be an abbreviation or full name (there is no standard for names or abbreviations of timezones), e.g. "Line Islands Time" or "LINT"
> - Right bracket, i.e. ")"

That means that string representation of the timezone is dependent on many things, such as `node` version, system locale and content of `/usr/share/zoneinfo` folder.